# ¿Cómo se podría combinar resultados que tengan el mismo alias?

Tags: postgresql

Quisiera una forma de combinar o sumar datos con el mismo alias "estado" como en el caso de Applied y No Qualified que se repiten en alias "estado" pero tienen diferente valor de "cantidad", ¿alguno podría echarme una mano?, esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT e.eac_clave AS "estado", COUNT(e.eac_clave)
FROM vacante v LEFT JOIN estadoaplicacion e ON e.vac_id = v.vac_id AND v.vac_id = 128 
JOIN candidatoxvacante cxv ON e.eac_id = cxv.eac_id GROUP BY e.eac_clave
UNION SELECT e.eac_clave AS "estado", CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 0
END
FROM vacante v JOIN estadoaplicacion e
ON e.vac_id = v.vac_id AND v.vac_id = 128 GROUP BY e.eac_clave 
ORDER BY "count"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es agrupar por estado y luego sumar la cantidad:

```
SELECT estado, SUM(cantidad)

FROM (

    SELECT e.eac_clave AS "estado", count(e.eac_clave) AS cantidad
    FROM vacante v 
    LEFT JOIN estadoaplicacion e ON e.vac_id = v.vac_id AND v.vac_id = 128 
    INNER JOIN candidatoxvacante cxv ON e.eac_id = cxv.eac_id 
    GROUP BY e.eac_clave

    UNION 

    SELECT e.eac_clave AS "estado", CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 0 END AS cantidad
    FROM vacante v 
    INNER JOIN estadoaplicacion e ON e.vac_id = v.vac_id AND v.vac_id = 128 
    GROUP BY e.eac_clave ) AS subquery

GROUP BY estado
ORDER BY estado;
```

Ten en cuenta que UNION elimina las filas duplicadas del resultado (si hay dos o mas filas con el mismo estado y cantidad quedará solo una luego del UNION), si quieres conservar los duplicados tienes que usar UNION ALL.